# Problems connecting Azure data to oData for Power BI

Tags: rest, azure-devops, powerbi, odata, powerquery

I'm trying to create a data source for Power BI from Azure via **Odata connection**. However, I face problems. When I'm making this connection, the following error appears:

```
DataSource.Error: Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Resources.HttpResource: Request failed:
OData version: 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. (Not Found)
OData version: 3, Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. (Not Found)
Details: DataSourceKind = ODataDataSourcePath=https://analytics.dev.azure.com/[MyWorkSpace]/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems
```

I already have a connection implemented using the same mechanisms, but when creating a new project I came across this error.

Please, help me!

Answer (score 0):

First, try to open the data with the browser to see whether you have any issue. Then, try to reset your login data in Power BI Desktop: `File > Options and settings > Data source settings`.

Comment: Hi, I tried to do this is the problem persists.
I already have the same mechanism applied to another project, I made the connections on both, only the second one worked

Comment: Are you able to open the data with the browser?

Comment: No, Because of the access rules, I can't. 

"{"error":{"code":"0","message":"VS403527: Access to data from the Analytics OData endpoint is not available for all users. "

Comment: Do you have the appropriate permission for this project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/analytics-security?view=azure-devops?